# How to Build/Update Cygwin GCC?

Tags: gcc, build, cygwin

I'm new to Stack Overflow and Cygwin. My problem is that how do you build/update Cygwin's GCC? I see a very obsolete version of gcc from the Cygwin setup.exe. Yes, I am on windows. Windows 7 to be exact.

So, how can I build/update Cygwin's GCC? I'd rather use Cygwin than MinGW+MSYS because I like things all in one, rather than things all over the place.

Thanks. (A step by step would be appreciated as I do not know anything about building a program from source)

Also, what would I need from Cygwin to build/update Cygwin's gcc? Do I install the  gcc from Cygwin first? Or do I just get the necessities from Cygwin and then build gcc using Cygwin and install gcc?

Sorry, but I do not excel at these types of subjects.

Comment: You don't need Cygwin, it is pants. Use the GCC implementation from Twilight Dragon Media at http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net.

Comment: I have cygwin because I want everything in one. I also have git on cygwin too (not very obsolete, but off by a release). I like to use the command line a lot and Cygwin fixes that for me (I also like the unix commands).

Comment: So unless I get a very reasonable answer to not use Cygwin and just use Mingw + MSYS, I will keep on trying to use Cygwin. Also, I am learning C++ and making programs on linux and windows.

Comment: Don't use CYGWIN as a development system.  Don't you want any kind of IDE and visual debugger on windows? Having a set of command line tools is not "all in one", it's piecemeal, shoddy, out of date.   If you want all in one, check out Eclipse C++ or NetBeans C++.  Now that's all in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can volunteer to help the maintainer, I guess. See [Why is the Cygwin package of XYZ so out of date?](http://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.old-packages) in [the Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq.html).